# Javascript replace() method failing?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `replace()` to get rid of `style="border-top-color: green;"` in a chunk of code.  The example below shows that it's not working, and I don't understand why.

Doing `alert(res);` seems to indicate that the full chunk of code (the HTMl of `<p id="demo">`) doesn't seem to be being scanned by `replace()`.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(' style="border-top-color: green;"', '');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<span id="demo">

    Point: (11, 2)
    <br>Slope: <span style="position: relative; top: 1px; left: -2px;">-</span>
    <div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">12</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span class="denom_display">7</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>Point-Slope Form: y – 2 = <span style="position: relative; top: 1px; left: -2px;">-</span>
    <div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">12</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span class="denom_display" style="border-top-color: green;">7</span>
    </div>(x – 11)
  </span>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace Fail</button>
```

Clicking "Replace Fail" will show you that the `style="border-top-color: green;"` is still present after it should have been removed.  Thoughts?

Comment: How about `Element.removeAttribute('style')` ?

Comment: are you sure your javascript is correctly hooked up with the html? so do something like alert('test'); inside the click to make sure it is even registered.

Comment: Why you are not adding ID to that specific `Span`

Comment: If you have an issue with string manipulation, don't include (irrelevant) HTML in your question. Put the string in a variable, try to manipulate that, and if you can't - ask a question

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<p>` cannot contain a `<div>`. Browsers know this and tend to try and compensate by closing the `<p>`, thereby changing the structure you intended to use.

Comment: console.log(str); would show what @j08691 is talking about.

Comment: And now that you've edited your example, it works.

Comment: I was actually just using the <p> tag as a test, but apparently that was causing the issue.  I'll look deeper on my end.

Comment: Now you edited your code *again* and this time wrapped your divs in spans, which is invalid just like when you wrapped them with paragraphs. You should really learn basic debugging techniques like running HTML through a validator and console logging your JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691: Interestingly, it still works with wrapping a <span> around.  So, it works with <span> and <div> as wrappers, but not <p>.  Interesting.......

Comment: Regardless of whether it works when using span wrappers it's invalid code and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Agreed, but I was just doing this for testing purposes and it seems odd that it would work with one version of invalid code and not with another.  Could it be related to the line breaks in the code chunk being scanned for replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will fail because a `<p>` cannot contain a `<div>`. If you retrieve the inner html of an element with an illegal structure, it will return an unexpected string. So this:

`var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`

will return this and only this:

> Point: (11, 2)
>       
> Slope: -

As soon as the browser hits the `div` it will stop returning anything past it. Therefore the string you want to replace is never returned, much less replaced.

You should ensure your markup is valid with W3C's validator: https://validator.w3.org/